# Vaadin - Internal error Please notify the administrator. Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, view, vaadin

I am developing an application in Vaadin where I have a view for Suppliers.

I am getting the error  `Internal error Please notify the administrator. Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue.` due to the calling of the method `categoriesToString` in my View.

### View

```
    public SupplierView(CrmService service) {
        this.service = service;
        addClassName("supplier-view");
        setSizeFull();
        configureGrid();

        form = new SupplierForm(service.findAllCategories(null));
        form.setWidth("25em");
        form.addListener(SupplierForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveSupplier);
        form.addListener(SupplierForm.DeleteEvent.class, this::deleteSupplier);
        form.addListener(SupplierForm.CloseEvent.class, e -> closeEditor());

        FlexLayout content = new FlexLayout(grid, form);
        content.setFlexGrow(2, grid);
        content.setFlexGrow(1, form);
        content.setFlexShrink(0, form);
        content.addClassNames("content", "gap-m");
        content.setSizeFull();

        add(getToolbar(), content);
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
        grid.asSingleSelect()
                .addValueChangeListener(event -> editSupplier(event.getValue()));
    }

    private void configureGrid() {
        grid.addClassNames("supplier-grid");
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.setColumns("name", "address");
        grid.addColumn(supplier -> supplier.categoriesToString())
                .setHeader("Categories");
        grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));
    }
}
```

The said method belongs to the class Supplier that can be seen below. This class has a Set of Category that I am trying to go trough in order to return all categories present in it.

### Supplier

```
@Entity
public class Supplier extends AbstractEntity {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
    private Set<Category> categories = new LinkedHashSet<>();


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


   public Set<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String categoriesToString(){
        String allCategories = "";
        for (Category c : this.categories) 
        {
            allCategories += c.getDescription();
        }
        
        return allCategories;
    }
}
```

In order to do some testing I tried to make the method just return "test" and in that scenario the word was indeed added to "Categories" column and no error was shown.

### Category class

```
@Entity
public class Category extends AbstractEntity{
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"categories"})
    private Supplier supplier;

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Why is this happening? Am I iterating through the set in a incorrect way?

Comment: Please enable logging on serverside. Probably there is some exception on the serverside

Comment: @AndréSchild how do I do that?

Comment: What servlet engine do you use on what platform?

Comment: Given, that you tagged the question with springboot, there should be logging
already, when you run it, to stdout. If you don't see any logging, search for it
(have you disabled it, do you log into files, ...) - this is essential for
developing any kind of software. If there is _no error at all_ (scroll back
too), then check also your browsers dev-console and the network tab there.

Comment: My guess is that you are experiencing a LazyInitializationException in `categoriesToString` because you are accessing the collection without an active Hibernate session.

Comment: @MarcoC how can I access the collection then?

Comment: I can't find in the above code how you are loading Supplier entities, but a way may be to use a JPA JOIN FETCH to load categories together with Supplier
Take a look at this article to get some idea
https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the fetch mode for your Entity, so it is defaulting to Lazy mode. Your current logic will only work with Eager mode (that would fetch the "categories" one-to-many relationship), but this is bound to create performance issues down the road as your data grows.

I wouldn't use logic inside my entities either (your categoriesToString method), but that is a different topic altogether.

You can either specify Eager loading on your entity as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "supplier")
private Set<Category> categories = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Or perform an additional query to fetch the related categories. Or even better, create a POJO or Spring Data Projection to fetch/map the appropriate data to. You can check [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions) for more info on that matter.